# How to handle file upload through windows form when using selenium grid?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#, grid

Writing tests with `c#/nunit` and running tests on the same machine I could use `System.Windows.Forms`, or call Autoit script to handle upload window that selenium can't interact with normally.

But this does not work if I run tests remotely.

Is there any option or trick to upload file using windows file upload dialog when executing tests remotely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help someone

In my case, there was file upload form, thats hidden. So after making it visible (in this case, change class), its possible to use SendKeys and send file path to that element, thus uploading file (if it exists in that VM)

Example:

```
    string filePath = "C://File//Path/File.txt";
    IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
    js.ExecuteScript("document.getElementById('import-file-btn').className = 'btn'");
    Find(import-file-btn).SendKeys(filePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not any option or trick to upload a file using the windows file upload dialog when executing tests remotely.